# Keeping Leading zero's for Route-UI Query Parameters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to use the route-ui url query to pull in two values, customerNumber and employeeID. EmployeeID has leading zeros. When I use the query url as below, it strips the leading zeros when I access the values through $StateParams.

```
 $stateProvider
    .state('person', {
    url: '/persons?customerNumber?employeeID',
    templateUrl: 'app/person/person.html',
    controller: 'PersonController',
    controllerAs: 'vm'    
    });
```

That is, employeeID changes from 005234243 to 5234243.
I have seen that you can cast to an integer or bool by doing the following:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('person', {
    url: '/persons?{customerNumber:bool}?{employeeID:int}',
    templateUrl: 'app/person/person.html',
    controller: 'PersonController',
    controllerAs: 'vm'    
    });
```

but you cannot cast to string this way, which means the leading zeros will be removed as an interpreted integer. How do I prevent the leading zeros from being removed in this way?

Comment: I tried locally and it doesn't loose the 0 from the number. Can you create a small example to illustrate the problem? Is the url created correctly (does it contain the leading 00 )?